# GeoServer GeoJSON WMS layer request in Mapbox

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a Mapbox GL JS web map which pulls GeoJSON layers from GeoServer. I've used the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) to find my problem lies in the 'GetFeatureInfo' get request URL which follows the following format (though in one line of course):

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
INFO_FORMAT=application/json&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.1.1&
WIDTH=970&
HEIGHT=485&
X=486&
Y=165&
BBOX=-180,-90,180,90&
LAYERS=CampusMap:dwt-campus-json&
QUERY_LAYERS=CampusMap:dwt-campus-json&
TYPENAME=CampusMap:dwt-campus-json&
```

My problem is that this link does not work, and when I run it in a browser I receive various WMS error files that are not very helpful. I really just want to be able to get this link to work so I can have this building footprints file load on my basemap and be query-able for future use.

Comment: please include the contents of one of the error files as they will be helpful to us.

Comment: Note KVP syntax for WMS is key[=value]& (the ampersand is at the end, not beginning)

Comment: Request is ok, it is just split on several rows for better readability. There does not need to be & after the last key so I would say that & is in between. Bbox covers the whole world which may not be intentional. Typename is not a WMS parameter but probably it is just skipped. I would check the bbox firs. Does GetFeatureInfo work with QGIS?

Comment: Ok, I can see that you have taken the example from https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html and it is really missing the SRS parameter. That's a bug in documentation.

Comment: feel free to fix the docs then

Comment: This request works for the demo layer "topp:states" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&QUERY_LAYERS=topp%3Astates&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-108.325%2C33.846%2C-99.448%2C42.723.

Comment: You had `http://.../wms?&...` so  `&` at the beginning of the pair, but if you read the [WMS version 1.1.1 specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1081&version=1&format=pdf) table 1, you can see that the pattern is: `http://host[:port]/path?{name[=value]&}`, where _URL prefix of service operation. [ ] denotes 0 or 1 occurrence of an optional part; {} denotes 0 or more occurrences. The prefix is entirely at the discretion of the service provider. _ Note too **The URL prefix must end in either a '?' (in the absence of additional server-specific parameters) or a '&'.**

Comment: @IanTurton a bit off topic, but last time I tried to change geoserver docs as a quickfix they weren't included/accepted

Comment: Did you do it as a PR? Usually accepted by me

Comment: Ok, @nmtoken, I can see from the history that the OP had  `http://.../wms?&...` before you edited the question. The query string itself is not special for WMS or other OGC services. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string. What you wrote as bold means that URL prefix can contain also one of more key-value pairs (server specific parameters) which is common with MapServer `http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywms.map&`

Comment: @user30184 yes of course many KVP are possible ( {} denotes 0 or more occurrences), I'm just quoting the  WMS 1.1.1 specification.

Comment: @IanTurton now I can't work out what I did, I thought I edited the documentation on GitHub and submitted, but I can't see how I could have done that now.

Comment: @nmtoken, it is really written that KVP should follow pattern key=value& but it is also mentioned that the meaning of & in the CGI standard is to be a separator `A client appends the necessary request parameters as
name/value pairs in the form "name=value&". The resulting URL shall be valid
according to the HTTP Common Gateway Interface standard [CGI], which mandates the presence of '?' before the sequence of query parameters and the '&' between each parameter.` None of the examples in the WMS standard has "&" at the end of the last KVP so the pattern is poorly written in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing the WMS GetFeatureInfo operation and a WFS GetFeature operation.

Your error is that the request is missing an SRS parameter, (e.g. SRS=epsg:4326&). You also have a typename parameter (which is not a GetFeatureInfo parameter), this isn't causing the problem, but it adds no meaning to the request and will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue is that you do not have a valid WMS `GetFeatureInfo` request as there are no `SRS` or `STYLES` there, so GeoServer will always throw an error.

However, I suspect you actually want a whole map as JSON in which case you would need a WMS `getMap` request, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
FORMAT=application/json&
REQUEST=GetMap&
EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.1.1&
WIDTH=970&HEIGHT=485&X=486&Y=165&BBOX=-180,-90,180,90&
LAYERS=CampusMap:dwt-campus-json&STYLES=
```

But that will fail because GeoServer doesn't provide GeoJSON as an output format (check the [capabilities](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities)), so you need to use a service that will send you vector features such as a WFS - try something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?
service=WFS&version=1.0.0
&request=GetFeature
&typeName=topp%3Astates1
&maxFeatures=50
&outputFormat=application%2Fjson
```